# iOS webview crashing only with iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Im aware that the UIWebView it's going to be deprecated for iOS13 soon and they wont accept apps with that on the store, but we are still working with it, and my main concern is, that while i can make it work in iOS 12 and lower, i can't with iOS 13, but it doesn't crash giving me a crash log or something, it just stops working without giving me anything, i don't know if that's what happens with this being deprecated soon or it's something inside my code or even Xcode.

Im working with OSX High Sierra and Xcode 9.2, the app it's configured for iOS 9 as target.

Answer (score 0):

This issue basically with the pushing the controller. So, try with present the controller.

```
webviewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

self.present(webviewcontroller, animated: animated, completion: nil)
```

if It works that nice otherWise present the webviewcontroller over the window.